# how to install pdfedit in ubuntu 19

Tags: libpng, master-pdf-editor

while installing it cant able to install

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt3-mt:

```
 libqt3-mt depends on libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4); however:
  Package libpng12-0:amd64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libqt3-mt (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pdfedit:
 pdfedit depends on libqt3-mt (>= 3:3.3.8-b); however:
  Package libqt3-mt is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package pdfedit (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.29-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.32.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-4ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
 libqt3-mt
 pdfedit
```

error msg came

Comment: Do you mean Ubuntu 19.04?  are there is no Ubuntu Core 19.  I don't know `pdfedit` and don't see it in any Ubuntu repo (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=pdfedit) but the one package I looked at you require is only available for xenial/16.04 (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libpng12) which it looks like you installed locally; libqt3 would be really old (current Qt is 5, old is 4) but you didn't include the messages of that attempt (only summary info)

Comment: yes its 19.04 I tried to install pdfedit but the dependencies are unable to install libqt3 is old version only but pdfedit support only qt3 dependencies that's why.